# How do I add a function to the sequence of functions which runs pre camera culling in Godot?

Tags: unity, camera, godot, culling, camera3d

In unity you can do:

```
Camera.onPreCull += OnPreCullCamera;
void OnPreCullCamera(Camera3D cam){
//...
}
```

But in Godot I don't know what the equivalent is. How do you add a function to the sequence which takes place before culling the camera. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is an equivalent, nor understand why you need it (I would expect that you can work in `_Process`). The closest I can think of is the `frame_pre_draw` signal of `RenderingServer`.

**Addendum**: You can get the `Viewport` inside of which a `Node` is with `GetViewport()` and get the `Camera3D` of said `Viewport` like this `GetViewport().GetCamera3D()`.

Comment: The reason I think I need it is this script: https://github.com/aras-p/UnityGaussianSplatting/blob/main/package/Runtime/GaussianSplatRenderer.cs on lines 38 and 182. I'm trying to convert it to Godot, but it's a process. I'm not entirely sure why the function on 182 needs to happen when it does, but maybe you can tell me if it does.

Comment: Does the behaviour differ from what you want in any significant way when you put this code in `_Process` or in a response to the `frame_pre_draw` signal instead? If so, be sure to document that in your question. If you can't determine that yet, then you have not yet identified a need for an equivalent to `OnPreCullCamera`, and you should proceed further with your experiments until you have concrete evidence one way or the other.